# Add relative complement of two data.table with rbind

Tags: r, data.table, rbind

I have a keyed `data.table` to which I would like to add rows from another table of the same key:

```
library(data.table)
key.cols <- c("ID", "Code")
set.seed(1)
DT1 = data.table(
  ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
  Code = LETTERS[seq(1,6)],
  Number = runif(6)
);DT1

DT2 = data.table(
  ID = c("a","a","c","b","b","b"),
  Code = LETTERS[seq(4,9)],
  Number = runif(6)
);DT2
```

I would like to only add to `DT1` rows from `DT2` of the keys that do not occur in `DT1` i.e. `rbind` a relative complement:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement

I can try and use `setops` and just add the keys letting the non-keyed columns be filled `NA` and join them afterwards:

```
DT1 <- rbind(DT1, fsetdiff(DT2[,(key.cols), with=FALSE], DT1[,(key.cols), with=FALSE]), fill=TRUE)
DT1[DT2, Number:=ifelse(is.na(Number), i.Number, Number), on = key.cols];DT1
```

Is there a less cumbersome way to do it?

Comment: Filter DT2 and rbind? `rbind(DT1, DT2[ (!paste(ID, Code) %in% paste(DT1$ID, DT1$Code)), ])`

Comment: Sure. But I will have to figure out how I to deal with a different vector of columns. Using paste it could get ugly

Comment: Possible duplicate / Related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly less cumbersome is:

```
rbind(DT1, DT2[!DT1, on = .(ID, Code)])
   ID Code     Number
1:  b    A 0.26550866
2:  b    B 0.37212390
3:  b    C 0.57285336
4:  a    D 0.90820779
5:  a    E 0.20168193
6:  c    F 0.89838968
7:  b    G 0.06178627
8:  b    H 0.20597457
9:  b    I 0.17655675
```

Perhaps more tractable would be to use `unique()`:

```
unique(rbind(DT1, DT2), by = c("ID", "Code"))
```

Comment: Yes. DT1 and DT2 reversed in the second argument, I believe

Comment: Oh.. yes. Fixed :). Anti-join and rbind.

Comment: btw @HannesZ you can replace `on = .(ID, Code)` with `on = key_cols`.